# Array being read by onDrawFrame while write

Tags: java, kotlin, opengl-es-2.0

I am having problems of read/write data of a list. There is a collection of items (vertex with initial position) on the screen in random positions. Sometimes I need to modify some of these positions (the quantity varies) when the user touches the screen.

The first time I implemented this I created a list of translateX and applied this transform on each vertex on the onDraw method.

I also duplicated the list to use the advantage of the method `System.arrayCopy` to see if I get any improvement.

Sometimes the list reads the list *while* it is being written. So the translate values are wrong in some items. Even using `System.arrayCopy()`.
The first solution was to implement a lock to always wait for the write calling the method `wait()`. When the writing finishes, it releases the `wait()` calling the `notify()` method. But this slows down the onDraw method, reducing the FPS.
Secondly I tried to skip reading using a boolean value to check if the data is being written. It does not solve.

Here a example:

```
const val COUNT = 100
val xForWrite = FloatArray(COUNT)
val xForRead = FloatArray(COUNT)
val scratch = FloatArray(16)
val translateMatrix = FloatArray(16)

//Called when the user touches the screen and moves the finger on it.
fun updateOffset(value: Float) {

    for (i in 0 until COUNT) {
      //Translate using value parameter and xForWrite, the translate is not always content and can vary based on each item.
    }

    System.arraycopy(xForWrite, 0, xForRead, 0, xForRead.size)
  }

//Called by the onDrawFrame method, every 1/60 seconds (60fps), can be less, respecting the openGL timing.
fun draw(mvpMatrix: FloatArray) {

  mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MVP_MATRIX)

  for (i in 0 until COUNT) {

    Matrix.setIdentityM(translateMatrix, 0)
    Matrix.translateM(translateMatrix, 0, xForRead[i], 0f, 0f)
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, translateMatrix, 0)

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
      positionHandle,
      COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
      GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
      false,
      vertexStride,
      items[i])

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, scratch, 0)

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
      GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
      drawOrder.size,
      GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
      drawListBuffer)

  }

}
```

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaXqcQpqYsQ

Any idea what I can do to solve this issue?